# Is there any way I can call datetime from SQL Server database with some time interval difference between multiple datetimes

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2016

I am trying to get data from a SQL Server table with particular interval difference between multiple entries.

```
SELECT 
    e.VEHICLE_ID, e.EMP_NAME, e.EPEC, a.LAST 
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE e 
INNER JOIN 
    AR_AR a ON a.EPEC = e.EPEC
```

This is the result I am getting from the above query:

```
+------------+----------+--------------+-------------------------+
| VEHICLE_ID | EMP_NAME |     EPEC     |          LAST           |
+------------+----------+--------------+-------------------------+
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:56.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:05.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:11:00.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:11.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:21.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:04.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:01.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:01.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:57.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:11.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:04.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:23.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:00.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:01.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:00.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:01.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:03.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:11.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:00.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:03.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:55.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:57.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:04.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:11.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:04.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:01.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:03.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:09.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:23.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:25.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:58.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:02.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:02.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:11.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:04.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:23.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:00.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:03.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:22.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:57.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:21.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:10.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:22.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:58.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:55.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:11.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:23.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:08.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:11.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:04.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:22.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:54.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:49:59.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:59.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:55.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:01.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:22.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:03.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:03.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:00.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:23.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:20.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:02.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:05.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:09.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:11:00.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:01.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:02.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:57.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:02.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:05.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:10.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:05.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:06.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:00.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:56.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:01.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:00.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:05.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:11:00.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:55.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:09.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:01.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:11:00.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:09.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:21.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:55.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:21.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:03.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:10.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:01.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:23.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:02.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:55.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:04.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:02.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:11.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:10.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:56.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:55.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:54.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:22.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:57.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:03.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:12.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:21.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:58.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:10.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:02.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:03.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:00.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:59.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:22.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:23.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:56.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:09.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:03.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:59.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:59.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:55.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:05.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:22.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:55.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:09.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:21.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:55.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:57.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:03.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:10.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:11:00.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:11:01.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:11:00.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:01.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:11.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:57.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:10.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:02.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:56.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:50:01.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:55.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:59.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:02.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:00.000 |
| AYB-369    | Rafay    | 627500027467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:58.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:47:01.000 |
| AKM-509    | Hassam   | 627500007467 | 2019-03-23 16:46:56.000 |
| Z-1376     | Zaryab   | 627500037467 | 2019-03-23 16:41:22.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:56.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:57.000 |
| BAK-424    | Saim     | 627500017467 | 2019-03-23 16:38:10.000 |
| jk-548     | 90iwsws  | 627500197467 | 2019-03-23 17:09:56.000 |
+------------+----------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

So if you notice that there are multiple entries of the same name but all of them have some difference in time... What I want is that my attached query return me the values in a manner that each same name entry has a time interval/difference of 5 minutes...

This is the database design:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (
      VEHICLE_ID nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL
    , EMP_NAME varchar(50) NOT NULL
    , EPEC datetime NOT NULL
    , LAST datetime NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Maybe some ordering and a [LEAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [LAG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) deal? I' not sure if they are available in SQL2016. Can you post the data set in text? No way I'm transposing that picture.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am not that much into SQL Server 2016 or any other versions... That's I will be requiring a particular solution... thanks

Comment: Well.. I gave you two leads to follow, LEAD and LAG, they are rather new constructs in MSSQL Server. If you cared to read any of the links I've posted, you can very quickly see they are both available since SQL2012.

Comment: Yeah read them already... Thanks...

Comment: I believe you are expecting someone to do it for you. I've asked for the dataset in an attempt to actually do your job. But you seem not very welcome to it. I'll ask you to read about [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your post to be compliant. Until then, I'm down voting this.

Comment: Oh actually I got you point in LEAD & LAG and it seems quite helpful to me... Also I'm sorry I will upload the dataset for you...

Comment: And how can I post the dataset?

Comment: @AbdulRafayAliKhan, what I do to include tabular data in a question is copy the SSMS sample data result with headers to the clipboard, paste as input on [this site](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/), copy/paste the output from that page into the question, and format as code. Include the table structure as code too (e.g. script the table as `CREATE` and paste to your question). Images attract downvotes because answerers often prefer to provide a tested solution and don't like transcribing images.

Comment: If we look at just one name - Saim - we see that this name is associated with a single vehicle_id. Are you assuming that any given name will always have the same vehicle_id for every row? This might be an important assumption about your data and can impact any solution.

Comment: Every User has it's own vehicle id... Like Saim has its own Hassam has it's own... No vehicle id is alotted to more than 1 user...

Comment: @DanGuzman i have tried implementing on you suggestion and it's the best I can do I guess

Comment: @AbdulRafayAliKhan, I think you could have done better. I edited your question with the changes I recommended.

Comment: @DanGuzman i appreciate your working and thank you so much for the favour... I am not quite exposed to the usage here...

Comment: @AbdulRafayAliKhan, I understand you are new. You should also add desired results in similar format and add the query you tried, even if not working as expected. Folks are more than winning to help when you've hit a roadblock after trying to solve the problem but it's off-topic to list requirements without an attempt at a solution. This is not a code-writing service.

Comment: How can I draw a table like you did?

Comment: Downvote removed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't check my code but it should be something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT 
        e.VEHICLE_ID, e.EMP_NAME, e.EPEC, a.LAST,
        LEAD([LAST], 1) OVER (PARTITION BY VEHICLE_ID ORDER BY [LAST]) nextLAST
    FROM 
        EMPLOYEE e 
    INNER JOIN 
        AR_AR a ON a.EPEC = e.EPEC
    ) t 
WHERE DATEDIFF(minute, [LAST], nextLAST) >= 5
```

Comment: I tried you query it's working fine but not full filling the need... I asked that it shows the results multiple times because the database has multiple values of time in it against a single username... right now your query is displaying only single result of the user instead I want multiple results of them with an average time time difference of 5 or more or just 5

Comment: Can you post the result that you want to get?

Comment: I just want it like if the date difference of a particular user is more than 5 minutes it than shows the result of the user with time difference 5minutes each time ...

Comment: I can't understand what you want to achieve. Post desired result table. Copy table in you question, paste it with your desired results

Comment: Well thank you for your answer I somehow managed to do it... Just did some amendments in your query and it worked for me...